# meaning of "get the first take under your belt"

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following script is from movie "Hitchcock"

> A:What if it's another Vertigo?
>
> B:You just **get the first take under your belt**, you'll be fine.

What does the bold part mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *take* is an attempt to get a scene on film by actors.  Usually it is not done correctly the first time so it is usual for there to be multiple "takes."

B is telling A that once he gets the first attempt out of the way, which won't be succesful, he'll be fine.  He is implying that no one's first attempt is successful.

*To have X under your belt* is an idiom that means "to have experienced X for the first time."

Comment: You might add some detail about [*under your belt*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/under-your-belt).